# SQL Sum with break-out (audits on inventory)

Tags: mysql, sum, running-totals

I'm having some difficulty getting this mysql query to work. I have the following tables

```
create table items (
    item_id int not null auto_increment,
    item_name varchar(25),
    primary key (item_id)
);

create table types
(
    type_id int not null auto_increment,
    type_description varchar(20),
    type_val_mod int,
    primary key (type_id)
);

create table log(
    log_id int not null auto_increment,
    item_id int not null,
    log_qty int,
    log_type int not null,
    primary key (log_id)
);
```

default values:

| type_id | type_description | type_val_mod |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | INVOICE | 1 |
| 2 | SALE | -1 |
| 3 | AUDIT | 0 |

and here is sample table:

| log_id | item_name | type_description | log_qty | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | WIDGET A | SALE | 1 | -1 |
| 3 | WIDGET A | SALE | 3 | -3 |
| 4 | WIDGET A | SALE | 2 | -2 |
| 5 | WIDGET A | INVOICE | 10 | 10 |
| 6 | WIDGET A | AUDIT | 60 | 0 |
| 7 | WIDGET A | SALE | 5 | -5 |
| 1 | WIDGET A | INVOICE | 100 | 100 |
| 11 | WIDGET B | SALE | 2 | -2 |
| 14 | WIDGET B | SALE | 5 | -5 |
| 13 | WIDGET B | INVOICE | 60 | 60 |
| 12 | WIDGET B | AUDIT | 10 | 0 |
| 10 | WIDGET B | SALE | 1 | -1 |
| 9 | WIDGET B | SALE | 1 | -1 |
| 8 | WIDGET B | INVOICE | 10 | 10 |
| 15 | WIDGET C | SALE | 1 | -1 |
| 16 | WIDGET C | INVOICE | 15 | 15 |
| 17 | WIDGET C | SALE | 1 | -1 |
| 18 | WIDGET C | SALE | 2 | -2 |
| 19 | WIDGET C | AUDIT | 10 | 0 |
| 20 | WIDGET C | INVOICE | 60 | 60 |
| 21 | WIDGET C | SALE | 5 | -5 |

I want to have a running total column where sale subtracts from column, invoice adds to it, but audit will reset the value to whatever the audit is. So it's a conditional sum that breaks out on audit type. Likewise each item is it's own group.

this is what I have so far, but I cannot get it to work and have been playing around with it for days.

```
with recursive rn as (
select log_id, item_name, type_description, log_qty,
 log_qty*types.type_val_mod as qty,
           row_number() over (partition by log.item_id order by log.log_id) as row_num,
           if(types.type_description="AUDIT",log_qty,null) as reset
    from log
        inner join types on log.log_type=types.type_id
        inner join items on log.item_id=items.item_id),
updated_log as(
    select log_id, item_name, type_description,row_num, log_qty, qty, reset,
           sum(if(type_description="AUDIT", 0,qty)) over (partition by item_name order by row_num rows between  0 preceding and 1 following) as new
    from rn
) select * from updated_log;
```

which gives: [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6mL9296tmFxVbGPiEUYK3o/0#&togetherjs=ygI9iU6NzH)

| log_id | item_name | type_description | log_qty | qty | row_num | reset | running_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | WIDGET A | INVOICE | 100 | 100 | 1 | null | 100 |
| 2 | WIDGET A | SALE | 1 | -1 | 2 | null | 99 |
| 3 | WIDGET A | SALE | 3 | -3 | 3 | null | 96 |
| 4 | WIDGET A | SALE | 2 | -2 | 4 | null | 94 |
| 5 | WIDGET A | INVOICE | 10 | 10 | 5 | null | 104 |
| 6 | WIDGET A | AUDIT | 60 | 0 | 6 | 60 | 104 |
| 7 | WIDGET A | SALE | 5 | -5 | 7 | null | 99 |
| 8 | WIDGET B | INVOICE | 10 | 10 | 1 | null | 10 |
| 9 | WIDGET B | SALE | 1 | -1 | 2 | null | 9 |
| 10 | WIDGET B | SALE | 1 | -1 | 3 | null | 8 |
| 11 | WIDGET B | SALE | 2 | -2 | 4 | null | 6 |
| 12 | WIDGET B | AUDIT | 10 | 0 | 5 | 10 | 6 |
| 13 | WIDGET B | INVOICE | 60 | 60 | 6 | null | 66 |
| 14 | WIDGET B | SALE | 5 | -5 | 7 | null | 61 |
| 15 | WIDGET C | SALE | 1 | -1 | 1 | null | -1 |
| 16 | WIDGET C | INVOICE | 15 | 15 | 2 | null | 14 |
| 17 | WIDGET C | SALE | 1 | -1 | 3 | null | 13 |
| 18 | WIDGET C | SALE | 2 | -2 | 4 | null | 11 |
| 19 | WIDGET C | AUDIT | 10 | 0 | 5 | 10 | 11 |
| 20 | WIDGET C | INVOICE | 60 | 60 | 6 | null | 71 |
| 21 | WIDGET C | SALE | 5 | -5 | 7 | null | 66 |

any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `GROUP BY...WITH ROLLUP` might be easier and simpler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want here is to make an audit row start a subgroup within its item group.  If we imagine that we have a virtual column defined like this:

```
IF(t.type_description = 'AUDIT', 1, NULL)
```

we can apply a partitioned running count over it like this:

```
COUNT(IF(t.type_description = 'AUDIT', 1, NULL))
OVER (PARTITION BY l.item_id ORDER BY l.log_id)  AS grp
```

The result will be this:

| log_id | item_name | type_description | ... | grp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | WIDGET A | INVOICE | ... | 0 |
| 2 | WIDGET A | SALE | ... | 0 |
| 3 | WIDGET A | SALE | ... | 0 |
| 4 | WIDGET A | SALE | ... | 0 |
| 5 | WIDGET A | INVOICE | ... | 0 |
| 6 | WIDGET A | AUDIT | ... | 1 |
| 7 | WIDGET A | SALE | ... | 1 |
| 8 | WIDGET B | INVOICE | ... | 0 |
| 9 | WIDGET B | SALE | ... | 0 |
| 10 | WIDGET B | SALE | ... | 0 |
| 11 | WIDGET B | SALE | ... | 0 |
| 12 | WIDGET B | AUDIT | ... | 1 |
| 13 | WIDGET B | INVOICE | ... | 1 |
| 14 | WIDGET B | SALE | ... | 1 |
| 15 | WIDGET C | SALE | ... | 0 |
| 16 | WIDGET C | INVOICE | ... | 0 |
| 17 | WIDGET C | SALE | ... | 0 |
| 18 | WIDGET C | SALE | ... | 0 |
| 19 | WIDGET C | AUDIT | ... | 1 |
| 20 | WIDGET C | INVOICE | ... | 1 |
| 21 | WIDGET C | SALE | ... | 1 |

You can see how this new column becomes an ideal partitioning criterion, which you can use together with `item_name` when calculating the running totals.  You just also need to adjust the argument of `SUM`: it should be `IFNULL(reset, qty)`, so that the audit value is also included in the total.

Here is the complete query:

```
WITH
  partitioned AS
  (
    SELECT
      l.log_id
    , i.item_name
    , t.type_description
    , l.log_qty
    , l.log_qty * t.type_val_mod AS qty
    , ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (PARTITION BY l.item_id ORDER BY l.log_id) AS row_num
    , IF(t.type_description = 'AUDIT', l.log_qty, NULL) AS reset
    , COUNT(IF(t.type_description = 'AUDIT', 1, NULL))
      OVER (PARTITION BY l.item_id ORDER BY l.log_id) AS grp
    FROM
      log AS l
      INNER JOIN types AS t ON l.log_type = t.type_id
      INNER JOIN items AS i ON l.item_id = i.item_id
  )
SELECT
  log_id
, item_name
, type_description
, log_qty
, qty
, row_num
, reset
, SUM(IFNULL(reset, qty))
  OVER (PARTITION BY item_name, grp ORDER BY log_id) AS new
FROM
  partitioned
;
```

Output:

| log_id | item_name | type_description | log_qty | qty | row_num | reset | new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | WIDGET A | INVOICE | 100 | 100 | 1 | *null* | 100 |
| 2 | WIDGET A | SALE | 1 | -1 | 2 | *null* | 99 |
| 3 | WIDGET A | SALE | 3 | -3 | 3 | *null* | 96 |
| 4 | WIDGET A | SALE | 2 | -2 | 4 | *null* | 94 |
| 5 | WIDGET A | INVOICE | 10 | 10 | 5 | *null* | 104 |
| 6 | WIDGET A | AUDIT | 60 | 0 | 6 | 60 | 60 |
| 7 | WIDGET A | SALE | 5 | -5 | 7 | *null* | 55 |
| 8 | WIDGET B | INVOICE | 10 | 10 | 1 | *null* | 10 |
| 9 | WIDGET B | SALE | 1 | -1 | 2 | *null* | 9 |
| 10 | WIDGET B | SALE | 1 | -1 | 3 | *null* | 8 |
| 11 | WIDGET B | SALE | 2 | -2 | 4 | *null* | 6 |
| 12 | WIDGET B | AUDIT | 10 | 0 | 5 | 10 | 10 |
| 13 | WIDGET B | INVOICE | 60 | 60 | 6 | *null* | 70 |
| 14 | WIDGET B | SALE | 5 | -5 | 7 | *null* | 65 |
| 15 | WIDGET C | SALE | 1 | -1 | 1 | *null* | -1 |
| 16 | WIDGET C | INVOICE | 15 | 15 | 2 | *null* | 14 |
| 17 | WIDGET C | SALE | 1 | -1 | 3 | *null* | 13 |
| 18 | WIDGET C | SALE | 2 | -2 | 4 | *null* | 11 |
| 19 | WIDGET C | AUDIT | 10 | 0 | 5 | 10 | 10 |
| 20 | WIDGET C | INVOICE | 60 | 60 | 6 | *null* | 70 |
| 21 | WIDGET C | SALE | 5 | -5 | 7 | *null* | 65 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uNd8dh_A)

Comment: Brilliant thank you. I kept thinking how I would do it in python but this is sweet and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

Without resetting:

```sql
SELECT *,
  SUM(log.log_qty * types.type_val_mod) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY items.item_name ORDER BY log.log_id) running_total
FROM log
JOIN items USING (item_id)
JOIN types ON log.log_type=types.type_id
ORDER BY items.item_name, log.log_id
```

With resetting on AUDIT:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
  SUM(types.type_description = 'AUDIT') 
      OVER (PARTITION BY items.item_name ORDER BY log.log_id) group_no
FROM log
JOIN items USING (item_id)
JOIN types ON log.log_type=types.type_id
)
SELECT *,
  SUM(CASE WHEN type_description = 'SALE' THEN -log_qty ELSE log_qty END) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY item_name, group_no ORDER BY log_id) running_total
FROM cte
ORDER BY item_name, log_id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/iu6hTD-B